# Eclipse RCP export fail

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

When I try to make a standalone program out of my RCP Project, the exported Product keeps telling me that startup failed. It produces a quite long error Log: http://tinypaste.com/7b15b2e2

Additionally the export fails for OS X x86_64. Only x86 works oO

Thanks for replies,
BigTeddy

Comment: Don't use tinypaste etc.  The link will break in a few days / weeks rendering your question meaningless.

Comment: Well pasting the thing in here would've been too much content... I'll use my own pastie clone thingie i made month ago...

Comment: Did you **try** pasting the content into your question?  Besides, your "pastie clone thingy" would only be a better idea if you could guarantee that the URLs would still work in a few years time.

Comment: Well actually it said i got a limit of 30,000(?) chars and i had like 40,000 chars so it didn't work... is there any alternative to the pastie things?

Comment: Well ... one alternative would have been to look carefully at the logfile, realized it contained a number of almost identical stack traces, and just pasted the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The salient part of the stacktrace is this:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError
```

This exception means that your Java code (transitively) depends on that particular class, but the Java runtime cannot find it on the classpath.

I'm not an RCP expert, but my guess is that your exported project is missing some JAR files, probably because of a problem in the project dependencies.  (It looks like some dependency on SWT is missing ...)

Comment: Okay that helped, thank you very much! :D (I simply added all SWT things i could find)

Answer (score 0):

If your computer you are developing on is 32bit, to be able to export 64bit RCP app I think you need Eclipse Deltapack (http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePDEBuild/ar01s02.html) installed.